# Why does anytime return NA in some cases

Tags: r

Why does anytime return NA in the first case but a valid result in the second case.

```
 str(A$X1)
 int [1:23744] 1487319525 1487323025 1487325865 1487332405 1487334780 1487353675 1487354135 1487354185 1487354195 1487354215 ...
> anytime(A$X1[1])
[1] NA
> anytime(1487319525)
[1] "2017-02-17 02:18:45 CST"
```

Answer (score 3):

That is a difference between `integer` and `numeric`.  Note that your vector is listed as `integer`.

So witness:

`R> library(anytime)
R> 
R> ivec <- c(1487319525L, 1487323025L, 1487325865L)
R> str(ivec)
 int [1:3] 1487319525 1487323025 1487325865
R> anytime(ivec)
[1] NA NA NA
R> 
R> fvec <- as.numeric(ivec)    ## convert to numeric
R> str(fvec)
 num [1:3] 1.49e+09 1.49e+09 1.49e+09
R> anytime(fvec)
[1] "2017-02-17 02:18:45 CST" "2017-02-17 03:17:05 CST" "2017-02-17 04:04:25 CST"
R>`

We walk a fine line here. *Numeric* values are taken a `POSIXct` if in a certain range.  Because C++ is strongly typed, your integer vector does make it to that test.

Moreover, we cannot just convert `integer` to `numeric` as we rely on this to work too:

```
R> anytime(20170217)
[1] "2017-02-17 CST"
R>
```

*Edit:* I caved.  The current development version in github does:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> ivec <- c(1487319525L, 1487323025L, 1487325865L)
R> anytime(ivec)
[1] "2017-02-17 02:18:45 CST" "2017-02-17 03:17:05 CST" "2017-02-17 04:04:25 CST"
R>
```

Comment: Could you set up a check for integers > 40000000L that would then be handled as  presumtive times?

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. It may have side effects.  But as you know, the package is open source and has a test suite so you could try it too.  I thjink it is pretty  rare to have `integer` type variables with POSIXct values ... as the latter is a `numeric`.  And as I demonstrated, pretty easy to convert back to `numeric`.

Comment: I added a [new branch for this](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/tree/feature/large_ints) and it may become a new feature after all.

Comment: And it is now in the mainline.